# How to import a file into another file in the same directory in python?

Tags: python, package

I have a project as the following structure:

```
project
 |-setup.py
 |-... some files (README, LICENSE, etc)
 |-package_name
   |-__init__.py
   |-utility.py
   |-m.py
```

Before deciding to make a pypi setup for it, I used:

```
from utility import *
```

to import `utility` into `m`. However, then when I install the package it can't import `utility`, and I had to change it to:

```
   from package_name.utility import *
```

Again, when I want to develop the project, I had to switch back to first one:

I wrote:

```
try:
    from package_name.utility import *
except:
    from utility import *
```

But I would like to know if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a relative import:
`from .utility import *`

To be able to use absolute import (like after installing the package, `from package_name.utility import *`) during development, you can install the package in editable mode:

- `pip install --editable .`
- or `python setup.py develop`

These commands will install the package in your environment in a way that all code changes will be immediately effective when you re-run your application, without having to reinstall the package.